# Find unique values in split range excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a dynamic search in excel which ends up giving me a split range (for example, [A4:D4,A6:D6,A8:D8]). I want to extract the unique values of each column of this split range, and then copy them to a new sheet. I've seen many solutions to finding unique values, but none are able to work with a split range like this. 
Thanks!

Code that i've done thus far (gives me an error):

```
Dim i As Long, j As Variant
j = dbws.Application.Transpose("$A$3:$D$3,$A$6:$D$6,$A$9:$D$9") '<== chooses unique cells for dropdown
With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For Each i In j
.Item(i) = i
Next
ws.Cells(1, Colcount).Resize(.count) = Application.Transpose(.Keys)
End With
```

Comment: @y-pel: I Downvoted/voted to close because you didn't include a [MCVE] , it looks like [no attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/), and it looks like [no research](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/) was done.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow: Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then edit your question to include the code, expected behaviour, and what is wrong... then we can try to help

Comment: @y-pel: thank you for editing your question to include the code. Please tell us what line of code gives the error, and what the error is? Are you having trouble with arun-time error, or the behaviour of the code, or the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a dictionary of dictionaries:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub CopyUniqueValues()
    Dim unionRng As Range, rng As Range, rng2 As Range, dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set unionRng = Union([A4:D4], [A6:D6], [A8:D8])
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each rng In unionRng.Areas
        For Each rng2 In rng.Cells
            If Not dict.exists(rng2.Column) Then
                dict.Add (rng2.Column), CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
                dict(rng2.Column).Add rng2.Value, 1
            Else
                If Not dict(rng2.Column).exists(rng2.Value) Then
                    dict(rng2.Column).Add rng2.Value, 1
                End If
            End If
        Next rng2
    Next rng

    Dim dictOutput As Object, key1 As Variant, key2 As Variant
    Set dictOutput = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For Each key1 In dict.keys
        dictOutput.Add key1, dict(key1).keys
    Next
    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
         For Each key1 In dictOutput.keys
             .Columns(key1).Range("A1").Resize(UBound(dictOutput(key1)) + 1, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dictOutput(key1))
         Next key1
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

**Data:**

[image: Data]

---

**Dataset:**

```
| 1 | 1 | 10 | 11 |
| 1 | 2 | 10 | 12 |
| 1 | 3 | 10 | 13 |
| 1 | 4 | 10 | 14 |
| 1 | 5 | 10 | 15 |
```

Comment: amazing! this works perfectly. I called the function with a unified range in it so I changed  " Set unionRng = Union([A4:D4], [A6:D6], [A8:D8])" to " Set unionRng = myRange". Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: glad it helped :-)